# Forging or Building packets in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have to send a packet, when viewed in hex is:

```
0A 00 2C 01 23 00 0C 00 B3 01
```

`0A 00` is the length which is 10.
`2C 01` is a identifier `12c` or could be a decimal packet id.
`23 00` is a version of dec 35.
`0C 00` is another version which is dec 12.
`b3 01` is 435.

which is from different variables and configs.

```
var packet_id = 300;
var game_version = config.game.version; // 35 from config
var update_version = config.update.version; // 12 from config
var date_version = config.date.version; // 435 from version
```

The length is then calculated from the size with the length. Then build this buffer and send it..

But how do I do this? I also was thinking that I want to predefine packet structure and just enter parameters like:

```
packet("versionCheck", // name of packet structure (defined somewhere
                 300 , // the packet id on the structure
          config.game.version, // the 2nd parameter for the versionCheck structure..... 
............
```

I am trying to use the packet package by bigeasy for node but I can only make it work with Parsing, not with Building packets.

Comment: in a dynamic packet, try to keep the fields that are the most static to the beginning of the packet this way you can't mess up searching for the fields when you have different length fields , also try to make separators which determinate when a field starts and ends.

Comment: @GeoPhoenix is there any helper package for that?

Comment: i'm not familiar with any particular module.. try to search to some of these links https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=buffer , https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/buffer

Comment: @GeoPhoenix I actually didn't know that packets was just buffers. I was looking for packet packages. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's actually a pretty basic example of packet, since everything is static. Something like this might work:

```
function Packet (length, id, v1, v2, other) {
    this._length = length;
    this._id = id;
    this._v1 = v1;
    this._v2 = v2;
    this._other = other;
}

Packet.prototype.toBuffer = function () {
    var buffer = new Buffer(this._length);

    buffer.writeUInt16LE(this._length, 0);
    buffer.writeUInt16LE(this._id, 2);
    buffer.writeUInt16LE(this._v1, 4);
    buffer.writeUInt16LE(this._v2, 6);
    buffer.writeUInt16LE(this._other, 8);

    return buffer;
}

var packet = new Packet(10, 0x12c, 35, 12, 435);

console.log(packet.toBuffer());
```

Also for parsing you don't need anything special, just same as `toBuffer`, but with `read` instead of `write` methods

Comment: Thanks, but there will be alot of packets and some packet data will be dynamic. So is it still recommended to use the basic buffer read and write? There will be around 1,000+ packets. length will be dynamic and automatically calculated based on the length of the data + itself.

Comment: I will try this as soon as I get home. and accept it.